# remove child item from expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, expandablelistview

I'm currently trying to create a button as a child item within a listview when the parent item is clicked, and then remove the button from the old parent item when a new parent is clicked and add the button as a child to the new parent item.

The main issue seems to come when attempting to delete the button from the old parent item.

Below is an example of before and after.

ListView: Before (Parent 1 clicked)

---

Parent Object 1

---

child1

---

[button]

---

Parent Object 2

---

child2

---

Listview After: (Parent 2 clicked)

---

Parent Object 1

---

child1

---

Parent Object 2

---

child2

---

[button]

The button is dynamically created without any issue when the first item is clicked.  However it seems to have issues deleting the button from the listview when a new parent is clicked.

Below is my code and  error log.  If more information is needed please request and I will provide the full source.

```
public void initParentListViewListeners(){

    listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            int lastChild = childArray.get(groupPosition).getNumOfChildren() - 1;

            if (lastParentClicked != null && listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, lastChild) != "Button") {
                int size = childArray.get(lastParentPosition).getNumOfChildren();
                //Remove button from old ArrayList
                childArray.get(lastParentPosition).getChildArray().remove(size - 1);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, lastChild) != "Button") {
                //Add Button to end of ArrayList
                childArray.get(groupPosition).getChildArray().add("Button");
                lastParentClicked = childArray.get(groupPosition).getChildName();
                lastParentPosition = groupPosition;
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

List Adapter Class:
Marked is where the error is occuring

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ChildObject> listDataHeader;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ChildObject> listDataHeader){
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    }

    @Override
    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
        ArrayList<String> setList = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getChildArray();
        return setList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        String childText = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) == "Button"){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_object_add_child, null);
            }
            else{
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item_child, null);
            }
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childObjContents);
        /******** Where error is happening ***********/
        if(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) != "Button"){
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), getChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            txtListChild.setText(childText);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition){
        ArrayList<String> setList = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getChildArray();
        return setList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return  listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount(){
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition){
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        String exerciseTitle = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getChildName();

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item_header, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(exerciseTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPostition) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

Error Log:

```
11-15 22:03:52.896    2651-2651/myapplication.android.commonsware.com.removelistviewitem E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: myapplication.android.commonsware.com.removelistviewitem, PID: 2651
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at myapplication.android.commonsware.com.removelistviewitem.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:54)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1356)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1651)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
11-15 22:03:57.380    2651-2651/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2651 SIG: 9
```